# Count the number of values between brackets in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where some `where` clauses contain arguments that come from report builder in parameter form.

So for example

```
Where xx = IN(1,2,3)
```

The 1,2,3 comes from report builder so the number of arguments can vary.

Now I want to count the number of arguments in the `IN` clause, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It is not clear what report builder returns and how you are using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there's a neater/ more efficient way, but this should work - assuming commas are only used to separate values and not within strings in the IN statement.

Effectively it's counting the commas (by identifying the length of the statement, minus the length of the statement with commas removed) and adding one.

`select len(xx) - len(replace(xx,',',''))+1`

Comment: This seem to do the job!